# Plotting of graph

Tags: java

Given an array of integers, I need to display a graph representing each integer.
For example, given an array {2,4,6,-3,-4,5,-1,-2,3}, the output on the console should be like:

```
     *     
     *     *
   * *     *
   * *     *     *
 * * *     *     *
 * * *     *     *
       * *   * *
       * *     *
       * * 
         *
```

I took the matrix approach, but so far I have been only able to achieve the horizontal version of the desired graph (90° clockwise rotated version of the desired graph, to be more precise).
How can I rotate my graph 90° in an anticlockwise direction to get the desired result? I tried transposing my result matrix but then the graph becomes the exact inverse of the desired result.

Here is the code,

```
public static char[][] plot(int[] array) {

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }

    if (min < 0) {
        min *= (-1);
    }

    char[][] tempArray = new char[array.length][max + min + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            for (int j = (min + 1); j <= min + array[i]; j++) {
                tempArray[i][j] = '*';
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            for (int j = min - 1; j >= min + array[i]; j--) {
                tempArray[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
}
public static void main(String...s){
  int[] arr = {2,4,6,-3,-4,5,-1,-2,3};
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(plot(arr)));
}
```

Also, I'm not able to nicely format the output matrix (I'm still looking at what is going on there), so I used Arrays.deeptoString().

Comment: if you get the wrong result exchange j and i. If that still is wrong loop in reverse direction(decrement the loop instead of incrementing.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others, that shows how the grid is printed and what the issue is with the result you get. Also, add an actual question to your post, you haven't asked anything yet. But be aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question.

Comment: HINT: swap the dimensions.  The 1st dimension (rows) should correspond to the _values_ of numbers, the second (columns) to the _positions_ of the numbers in the given array.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Are you talking about making changes to this code or writing a new one?

Comment: Change or rewrite? Take your pick, whichever is easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I make own plotter (`plot0`) which write directly to the output stream char by char, line by line:

```
private static void plot0(final int... numbers) {

    final int cols = numbers.length;
    final IntSummaryStatistics stat = Arrays.stream(numbers).summaryStatistics();
    final int max = stat.getMax();
    final int min = stat.getMin();

    final int rows;
    if (min < 0) {
        rows = Math.max(0, max) + ~min + 2;
    } else {
        rows = max;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        final int val = Math.max(0, max) - i;
        if (0 == val) {

            continue; // do not plot zero
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            final int num = numbers[j];
            System.out.print(
                    0 < num && 0 < val && num >= val
                            || 0 > num && 0 > val && num <= val
                                    ? '*'
                                    : ' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

I made some small changes in your code ( rename to `plot1`), but basically the original thinking works.

1. change `Arrays.deepToString(tempArray[i])` to `new String(tempArray[i])`
2. two dimensional array is not printable, use a line of char instead
3. fill zero values with `' '` in `Arrays.fill(tempArray[i], ' ');`
4. missing skip 0 value from print, the baseline is visible
5. end of line after fill all `'*'` values, not before
6. the `'*'` values override the `' '`, so you cannot write directly to the output.

---

```
private static void plot1(final int... array) {

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (final int element : array) {
        if (element > max) {
            max = element;
        }
        if (element < min) {
            min = element;
        }
    }

    if (min < 0) {
        min *= -1;
    }

    final char[][] tempArray = new char[array.length][max + min + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(tempArray[i], ' ');
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            for (int j = min + 1; j <= min + array[i]; j++) {
                tempArray[i][j] = '*';
            }
        } else if (array[i] < 0) {
            for (int j = min - 1; j >= min + array[i]; j--) {
                tempArray[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new String(tempArray[i]));
    }
}
```